# Maria DB : Alter a field to a PERSISTENT Calculated

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, calculated-columns

I have created a table and I wish to make a Computed Column from the concatenated values of three other fields in the table.

I want this Computed Field to take place at INSERT or UPDATE, so I am specifying PERSISTENT

I have tried the following code (in various ways) in phpMyAdmin but always get errors, which seem to be referencing immediately after ALTER table

I did not see a way of doing this when adding the field in phpMyAdmin, so I hoped I could ALTER it.

```
Alter TABLE 'tlImages'
CHANGE COLUMN tlImageQuery
AS CONCAT(tlImgTitle,"~",tlImgDescrip,"~",tlImgWhereWhen) PERSISTENT;
```

MariaDB version 10.0.29-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server

phpMyAdmin . Version information: 4.0.10.18

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, lose single quotes around the table name, they are not suitable for this purpose. Use backticks or nothing.

You will still get a syntax error further in the statement, because `AS` clause should be in brackets. Add them.

You will still get a syntax error because you are missing column type before the `AS (...)` clause, add it.

You will still get a syntax error because `CHANGE COLUMN` needs two column names, old and new, use `MODIFY` instead.

```
Alter TABLE `tlImages` 
  MODIFY COLUMN tlImageQuery VARCHAR(128) 
  AS (CONCAT(tlImgTitle,"~",tlImgDescrip,"~",tlImgWhereWhen)) PERSISTENT
;
```

(Type `VARCHAR(128)` is given just as an example).

Comment: Brilliant - works a treat.  I hope this can be an example for anyone else, as I could not find anything close on the web.